# Linux Bash script fails with a syntax error

Tags: shell-script

Trying to get this bash script to work:

```
#!/bin/bash

for result in $(cat ./fn7);
for dip1 in $(cat ./fn4);
for dip2 in $(cat ./fn5);
for dip3 in $(cat ./fn6);
for ip in $(seq 0 255);
ifconfig > ./fn1;
cat ./fn1 |grep "broadcast" > ./fn2;
cat ./fn2 |cut -d " " -f10 > ./fn3;
cat ./fn3 |cut -d "." -f1 > ./fn4;
cat ./fn3 |cut -d "." -f2 > ./fn5;
cat ./fn3 |cut -d "." -f3 > ./fn6;
echo $dip1.$dip2.$dip3. > ./fn7;
ping -c 1 $result.$ip > ./results
```

It fails with a error of:

```
./IP-Sweeper.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `for'
./IP-Sweeper.sh: line 4: `for dip1 in $(cat ./fn4);'
```

Comment: Being POSIX compliant and using `#!/bin/sh` has its downsides. Primarily not being able to take advantage of Bash's additional features. If you need those features or don't need to be portable it doesn't matter as long as your remember that `sh` is portable.

Comment: The above script isn't using any bashisms, and it is better for beginners to understand writing proper scripts from the beginning.

Comment: That is your opinion and I am supplying my own competing opinion. I would point out that most guides are specifically Bash guides and while understanding the difference is important; most people will learn Bash before they know that `sh` exists.

Comment: It isn't possible to correct this script without knowing what it should do as it has a lot of syntax and logic errors that are misleading.

Comment: its designed to pull my IP address and then chop off the end octet. Then run a sequence on the 4th octet with the ping command sending a single packet to all computers in my network segment and let me know which are alive targets. This was a script I am trying to get to work for my OSCP course to make things easier and to prove to myself I understand scripting.

Answer (score 7):

[The syntax for a `for` loop](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_01.html) is like this:

```
for x in {list}
do
    command...
    command...
done
```

There is neither `do` nor `done` on any of your loops.

[Bash Guide for Beginners](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/) and [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) are good references on syntax and best scripting practices.

Comment: Tried it still doesn't work for what ever reason it doesn't populate the varibles with the supplied information in the files.

Comment: @Jason please add this new script to your question. Ideally cut it down to the smallest example illustrating what doesn't work. Remember to explain what input you give this example, what it gives you back and what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is in not having a `do done` block after your for statement.