# Bash Script problem with Variables from files

Tags: shell-script

Trying to get this script to work how ever I get an error no matter how I try to set the varibles. After checking the varibles are not being set from the files that the information is in.
[image]

Comment: Please use [proper formatting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)—no need to use images to post code. You should also apply the advice received in [your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/280103/linux-bash-script) before asking further questions about the same script.